# VLC with python won't play track

Tags: python, vlc

I would like to create this very basic program using the VLC API. I want it to play a simple wav-file in background and it works perfectly, execpt if there is an 's' at the beginning of the path-string 'filename' (e.g.'F:\\projects\Python\\six\\L.wav'):

```
def setupPlayer(filename):
    instance = vlc.Instance()
    media = instance.media_new(filename)
    player = instance.media_player_new()
    player.set_media(media)

    return player

player.play()
```

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but… never use unescaped backslashes in a non-raw string literal. Any of `r'F:\projects\Python\six\L.wav'` or `'F:\\projects\\Python\\six\\L.wav'` or `'F:/projects/Python/six/L.wav'` is fine, but the way you've done it, you're relying on the fact that none of `\p`, `\P`, `\s`, or `\L` is a special backslash escape in any version of Python, which… I _think_ is true, but I'm not positive, and why should you want to rely on that?

Comment: I would recommend using os.path.join() to build paths instead of using the string literals.

Comment: @Tadgh: For literal paths, there's no reason to use `os.path.join`.